# Sometimes I do not see a complete comment at stack overflow only 

Tags: support, comments

Currently you can see this on [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436264/calculates-b-w-two-row)
the comment from Brave ali Khatri.
I noticed this kind of behaviour before and after some time I could see the complete comment

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Can you elaborate on what you're seeing?

Comment: My I want to Add Where Cluse here w hich Identify my ITEM Basicaly that Calculation is For Current Stock Status.... – Brave ali Khatri 13 mins ago -- I think the 3 dots are an indicator that the comment is truncated

Comment: Nope, it's not. Some people just type like that.

Comment: Maybe he fell asleep while writing the comment.  (But then why would he type the "..."?)

Comment: @Jim Lewis The intention was probably to express something like : etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments may have a length of six hundred characters (This is displayed while you are typing). You cannot enter more characters in the comment box, so there is no need to truncate longer comments.

The trailing `...` have been entered by the user.

[Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) is used in some languages when trailing parts of a sentence will be omited.

Comment: Well It may be possible or not. Before accepting the answer, I will look for repetations for some days.

Comment: Accepted. I did not see new incarnations of the problem.